# Unbiased estimators for uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, sample, estimators, uniform-distribution, unbiased-estimator

I have a given question that I just cannot figure out. From what I can understand, both estimators would be unbiased (since e_1 is the sample mean and e_2 is an unbiased estimator for uniform distribution), which seems unlikely. I appreciate any help or hints.

Every day you take the train to the work. You know that the train arrives regularly every $\theta$ minutes, but you do not know θ. For a total of n ∈ N days, you leave your house at a random time and note the waiting times $X_1$,$X_2$ . . . , $X_n$ for your train to arrive. In particular, $X_1$, . . . , $X_n$ $\sim$ Unif(0, $\theta$) and we assume that $X_1$, . . . , $X_n$ are independent. Check if
$$e_1(x_1,...x_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_1$$and$$ e_2(x_1,...x_n)=\frac{n+1}{n} max \{x_1,..x_n\}
$$
are unbiased estimators of $\theta$. If necessary, modify the estimators (by multiplying them with a suitable factor), such that they are unbiased.

Comment: The first is a number in the middle of the observations while the second is larger than the biggest observation.  So the second is always larger than the first.  This means they cannot both be unbiased. Can you spot which one is obviously biased?

Comment: from your answer I would guess that the second one is biased. thank you

Comment: If the train always arrives with gaps of exactly $\theta$ minutes, then you will never wait more than $\theta$ minutes.  So an estimate of $\theta$ which is less an observed wait will be too small

Comment: sorry, now i am confused. with the first one I get a value in the middle of the observations, with the second I get somewhere around the maximum. so the second is unbiased and I need to change the first one?

Comment: The first is certainly biased and the question asks for the multiplier to make it unbiased.  You still need to check whether the second is biased or not.